# Round only numeric elements in cell array with different data types

Tags: matlab, rounding, cell-array, elementwise-operations, heterogeneous-array

I have a cell with different types of variables (double & strings), I want to round the numeric elements in the cell.
`round` function can work only with arrays and not with cells, so I'm trying to use `cell2mat` - but this function can't be used in case of different elements types in the cell.

Any idea how can I round the numeric elements in this cell? Of course I don't want to do loop over the cell elements.

Comment: You can't do that without looping afaik. You can use `cellfun` , but that's just a loop in disguise. Cells are notoriously hard to work with if you want to avoid looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by **Adriaan**, this can be done with `cellfun`:

```
function testCell = q38476362

  testCell = {'t','h',1.004,'s',[],'i',4.99,[],'a',[],'ce',10.8};
  isnum = cellfun(@(x)~isempty(x) & isnumeric(x),testCell);
  testCell(isnum) = num2cell(round([testCell{isnum}],0));
```

```
testCell = 

    't'    'h'    [1]    's'    []    'i'    [5]    []    'a'    []    'ce'    [11]
```

If your cell array is random in terms of where the `string`s and where the `double`s are, there's not much you can do besides loop/`cellfun`/[bruteforce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38477288/3372061). If however, there is some periodicity (e.g. "a string is always followed by two `double` entries") you might be able to construct some indexing vector that would get you the values without having to iterate (explicitly or implicitly).

Comment: Dev-iL, thanks, your answer is great but not working for me in case that cell contain also empty elements ([])

Answer (score 1):

You want to take advantage of the `str2double` ability to convert non-numeric types into NaN.

Say you have a cell like:

```
 A = {'1.999','3.1415','pie','??'}
 B = round(str2double(A))

 B =

 2     3   NaN   NaN
```